# Static variable used for Recurssion check

Tags: apex, trigger, recursion, static, cross-object

**Scenario:**
I have two objects - Object A and Object B.Object A has recursion checking mechanism using Static Boolean variables covering different events(IsBeforeUpdate,IsBeforeInsert etc..)
I have two apex classes (Class 1 and Class 2) running on Object B that updates Object A on after update.

**Question:**
Let us say an update operation happens on Object B.
whats happens to the Static Boolean (IsBeforeUpdate on Object A) will it be set to false by the first class 1 ? and second class 2 will not be able do its update on Object A?
if this is true , how can i make sure both my class 1 and 2 from Object B update Object A?

```
//MasterTaskTrigger
if (trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter) 
{
    handler.afterUpdate(trigger.old, trigger.oldMap, trigger.new, trigger.newMap);
    system.debug('inside After Update');
}

//This is an handler for Task Object
public class TriggerhandlerTask extends TriggerHandler
{
    public void afterUpdate(List<Task> originalTask,Map<ID, Task> originalTaskMap,List<Task>updatedTask,Map<ID, Task>  updatedTaskMap) 
    {
        if(afterUpdateHasRun()) 
        {
            return;
        }
        //Call Class 1 - has logic to update Object A 
        Class1 Cs =  new Class1();
        //Call Class 2 - has logic to update Object A
        Class2 Cs =  new Class2();
    } 
}

//this handler is extended across all other objects Triggerhandlers
public virtual class TriggerHandler 
{
    public   static  boolean isBeforeInsertFirstRun   = true;
    public   static  boolean isBeforeUpdateFirstRun   = true;
    public   static  boolean isBeforeDeleteFirstRun   = true;
    public   static  boolean isAfterInsertFirstRun    = true;
    public   static  boolean isAfterUpdateFirstRun    = true;
    public   static  boolean isAfterDeleteFirstRun    = true;
    public   static  boolean isAfterUndeleteFirstRun  = true;

    protected boolean beforeInsertHasRun() 
    {
        if (isBeforeInsertFirstRun) 
        {       
            return isBeforeInsertFirstRun = false;
            System.debug('---->isBeforeInsertFirstRun'+isBeforeInsertFirstRun); 
        }
        return true;
    }
    protected boolean beforeUpdateHasRun() 
    {
        if (isBeforeUpdateFirstRun) 
        {
            return isBeforeUpdateFirstRun = false;
            System.debug('---->beforeUpdateHasRun'+beforeUpdateHasRun); 
        }
        return true;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You must [edit] your post to illustrate the code pattern. Please try to only include relevant code if you can. Imagine if you were going to try to reproduce this issue in a new developer org.

Comment: @AdrianLarson i have updated the original post with the pattern that i am trying to implement, my question is will my class2 on task be able to update Object A ? why i am asking this because i have a doubt that if class1 completes the update , the boolean isBeforeUpdateFirstRun is set to false (for Object A instance) and second class 2 will not be able to update Object A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle recursion as a *locking mechanism*. That means that the trigger should first see if it's locked, and if not, lock itself, and when done, unlock itself. Here's the basic design:

```
public class TriggerLocks {
    public static Boolean triggerA_beforeUpdate = false;
    // and so on
}

trigger triggerA_BeforeUpdate on A (before update) {
    if(TriggerLocks.triggerA_beforeUpdate) {
        return;
    }
    TriggerLocks.triggerA_beforeUpdate = true;
    // Do your logic here
    // When done...
    TriggerLocks.triggerA_beforeUpdate = false;
}
```

This way, if you have two or more updates on A records, you can do both of them without the trigger flag getting in the way.

Note: "Class 1" nor "Class 2" should update the Boolean flag without good reason. The data is conceptually internal to the trigger itself, but due to language limitations, can't actually be protected in the same way. The trigger, and *only* the trigger, should modify that flag directly. This limits the responsibility of breaking recursion to just the single trigger's logic.

---

Here's a "not very optimized" version of a handler I might build to help with consistency.

```
public virtual class BaseTriggerHandler {
    static Map<Type, BaseTriggerHandler> cache = new Map<Type, BaseTriggerHandler>();

    Boolean inBeforeInsert = false, inBeforeUpdate = false, inBeforeDelete = false,
            inAfterInsert = false, inAfterUpdate = false, inAfterDelete = false, inAfterUndelete = false;

    protected virtual void beforeInsert(SObject[] records) {

    }
    protected virtual void beforeUpdate(SObject[] oldRecords, SObject[] records) {

    }
    protected virtual void beforeDelete(SObject[] oldRecords) {

    }
    protected virtual void beforeUndelete(SObject[] records) {

    }
    protected virtual void afterInsert(SObject[] records) {

    }
    protected virtual void afterUpdate(SObject[] oldRecords, SObject[] records) {

    }
    protected virtual void afterDelete(SObject[] oldRecords) {

    }
    protected virtual void afterUndelete(SObject[] records) {

    }
    void doBeforeInsert(SObject[] records) {
        if(!inBeforeInsert) {
            inBeforeInsert = true;
            beforeInsert(records);
            inBeforeInsert = false;
        }
    }
    void doBeforeUpdate(SObject[] oldRecords, SObject[] records) {
        if(!inBeforeUpdate) {
            inBeforeUpdate = true;
            beforeUpdate(oldRecords, records);
            inBeforeUpdate = false;
        }
    }
    void doBeforeDelete(SObject[] oldRecords) {
        if(!inBeforeDelete) {
            inBeforeDelete = true;
            beforeDelete(oldRecords);
            inBeforeDelete = false;
        }
    }
    void doAfterInsert(SObject[] records) {
        if(!inAfterInsert) {
            inAfterInsert = true;
            afterInsert(records);
            inAfterInsert = false;
        }
    }
    void doAfterUpdate(SObject[] oldRecords, SObject[] records) {
        if(!inAfterUpdate) {
            inAfterUpdate = true;
            afterUpdate(oldRecords, records);
            inAfterUpdate = false;
        }
    }
    void doAfterDelete(SObject[] oldRecords) {
        if(!inAfterDelete) {
            inAfterDelete = true;
            afterDelete(oldRecords);
            inAfterDelete = false;
        }
    }
    void doAfterUndelete(SObject[] records) {
        if(!inAfterUndelete) {
            inAfterUndelete = true;
            afterUndelete(records);
            inAfterUndelete = false;
        }
    }
    // The only method you need to call
    public void dispatch() {
        if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore) {
            doBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore) {
            doBeforeUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore) {
            doBeforeDelete(Trigger.old);
        }
        if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
            doAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) {
            doAfterUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter) {
            doAfterDelete(Trigger.old);
        }
        if(Trigger.isUndelete && Trigger.isAfter) {
            doAfterUndelete(Trigger.new);
        }
    }

    protected BaseTriggerHandler() {

    }

    // Singleton/factory
    public static BaseTriggerHandler getHandlerFor(Type handlerType) {
        if(!cache.containsKey(handlerType)) {
            cache.put(handlerType, (BaseTriggerHandler)handlerType.newInstance());
        }
        return cache.get(handlerType);
    }
}
```

And here's a possible implementation:

```
public class TaskTriggerHandler extends BaseTriggerHandler {
    protected override void afterUpdate(SObject[] records) {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    }
}
```

And here's the trigger you use to actually call this entire framework:

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    BaseTriggerHandler.getHandlerFor(TaskTriggerHandler.class).dispatch();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i am trying to implement a trigger design pattern in my Org, lot of trigger design patterns are using the handlers in the middle to manage Recursion , if you can share a pattern that can handle complex requirements and recursion without running into this type of issue i can use it a base and build on it.

Comment: This is intriguing as it looks like it deals with the use case when more than 200 sobjects are in a DML statement where other "traditional" static recursion flags basically prevent the trigger from doing anything on sobjects 201+

Comment: @cropredy Shh. It's a secret to everybody.

Comment: @Kiran It took me a bit to write something, but let me know if this example is useful.

Comment: Always get uncomfortable when I see one boolean flag for all columns (and all rows). If the trigger is handling changes to two different fields, a change to the first field will mean a change to the second field made after the trigger has fired once will be not acted upon by the trigger.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks a lot for your comment, it's really a well-structured pattern, but a quick question you have said it not a very optimised structure is there something that I should take care of? one more thing on the trigger when you call BaseTriggerHandler.getHandlerFor(TaskTriggerHandler.class).dispatch(????); } you are not passing trigger.new or old values into the method - any reason?

Comment: @KeithC This framework, like all frameworks, can't handle workflow field updates. If that's a concern, then it's entirely possible that you need a more complex recursion algorithm. I didn't want to get too hung up on building a correct, but massive, trigger handler framework (I've built a framework that was over 400 lines of code *just* for the base class), but to give a simple (copy-pasted) illustrative framework. This one certainly isn't a silver bullet to handle all types of situations. That said, if you want, you can suggest an edit for how you'd do it, if you like.

Comment: @Kiran It doesn't handle recursive changes to the *same object* but different records. It also doesn't have an answer for workflow field updates. If you need something like that, you might need to come up with something far more complicated. This is just more of an illustrative example that would work in simple use cases. As for the other bit, passing Trigger.new/old as a parameter to the function: you can do it either way. There's no difference either way once you start using a framework like this, as you'll have to cast from generics to specific types of records for each handler.

Comment: @sfdcfox Guess what I'd like to see in answers like this is mention that while the single boolean flag is generally the best solution (because it is simple) in a small number of cases it may result in changes being missed. On this forum it is often presented as all good and no bad.

Comment: @KeithC Fair enough. This framework does properly handle recursion, just not workflow field updates or recursive updates to "parent" or "child" records in the same object.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have one quick question, most common approaches use static boolean to handle recursion but your example you have used just boolean field, is there a reason why you chose not to use Static??

Comment: @Kiran The variables are part of a class-- each copy references a specific trigger handler class. If they were static, you could only handle one trigger at a time. This design allows you to handle multiple triggers in any reasonable order of recursion. You might want to study it a bit to see how it works.